# What would prevent me from using this valve for water?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, hydraulics, valves

https://www.kingstonvalves.com/product/ksv25cr-stainless-steel-asme-soft-seat-safety-valve/

Looking to use this for water instead of air. I haven't seen a good reason not to as the physics of the pressure relief valve don't change depending on the fluid. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Application is to allow water out of a vessel, once it is above a threshold pressure.

Comment: What is the application?  Using a pressure relief valve at all may not be a sensible way to control a pressure hazard in a water system.

Comment: Application is to allow water out of a vessel, once it is above a threshold pressure.

Comment: it is difficult to guess what would prevent you from doing something ... we do not know you ... if you are asking if the valve can be used with water, then yes ... it is designed for corrosive environments

Comment: I would imagine it will require more force to close a valve on an incompressible fluid than a compressible one even if the pressure difference across the valve in the direction of the flow is the same? For flow control valves they can get stuck open, but they aren't pressure relief valves it's not an entirely relevant comment :) just something to consider

Answer (score 0):

Corrosion susceptibility, for one thing. a valve that works fine in air might have a corrosion problem in water service.

Comment: It is stainless steel, so it should be fine, seems wrong to use an air valve for water, but I haven't seen anything wrong yet

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's no way to pipe the discharge to a safe location.  Fine for compressed air, but certainly not for steam or combustible gases, and either not desireable, or unacceptable for water.

Comment: I am confused. Isn't the point of a pressure relief valve to discharge the fluid when it is above a pressure?

Comment: Assume the water can go somewhere